# Struggling looking forward to avoid a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have the following for loop :

```
other_values=[3,4,5,3,2]

values=[5]
for i in range(len(other_values)):
    values.append(values[i] * (1 + ((other_values[i] / 100)/50)))
print (values)
```

And provides the desired output.

When looking forward to turn it to a list compreh the problem I have is that it outputs that:

```
 list index out of range
```

this is what I tried:

```
values=[5]
values=[values[i] * (1 + ((other_values[i] / 100) / 360)) for i in range(len(other_values)) ]
```

The logic behind is to loop over the last value in values and apply the function and add it on to values list that begins with 5

Comment: You want to describe your logic?

Comment: I can't think of a sane way to do what you want as a list comprehension. List comprehensions get their own scope, so `values` is not being extended whilst the list comprehension is being evaluated. There's also no reason to have a list comprehension, it's not somehow inherently better; you're creating an issue for yourself. A better modification is to get rid of `range(len())` and use `enumerate`

Comment: That is because your loop adds elements to `values` with each iteration. The list comprehension only returns one final list in the end and in "its eyes", `values = [5]` through the whole process

Comment: Python is built around some principles and one of them is: *readability counts*. Your formula is complex enough on it own. If you squeeze it into a comprehension it will not count as readable anymore.

Comment: Are doing this just to get the final element which is the result of the rolling computation?

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehension approach doesn't work because your value list is not updated at every step but only in the end. As a consequence when you look for the `value[2]` where `value = [5]` (since it did not get updated) it returns you an error because you are looking for the value of an element that doesn't exist. If I were you I would stick to the for loop which is simpler in this case.

If you want to use list comprehension to make your code simpler, this code should work

```
import numpy as np
other_values=[0, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2]
5 * np.cumprod([1 + val /500 for val in other_values])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)):

```
from itertools import accumulate

other_values=[3,4,5,3,2]

values = list(accumulate([5] + other_values, lambda a, b: a * (1 + ((b / 100)/50))))
print(values)
```

Prints:

```
[5, 5.003, 5.007002399999999, 5.012009402399999, 5.015016608041439, 5.017022614684655]
```